# Some questions about convexity, compact sets

Tags: convex-analysis

> Consider $W = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x_1^2 + x_2^2 < 4, x_1 \geq 1, x_2 \geq -0.5\}$
>
> Is $W$ closed? Is $W$ convex? Is $W$ open? Is $W$ bounded? Explain your answers.

I'm a bit puzzled when I encounter such questions. I don't know how you easily see if a set like the one above is convex, open, closed etc. Can anybody help me?

Comment: It helps to know that any intersection of convex sets is also convex.

Answer (score 1):

Hints :

Is it closed ? Consider the series $x_n = (2 - \frac{1}{n},0)$

Is it convex? Is the intersection of convex spaces convex?

Is it open? Consider the point $(1,0)$ and its neighbourhoods

Is it bounded? Can you find a point $x$ in $W$ such that $||x||>2$? Are all norms equivalent in $\mathbb{R}^2$?